# Synthetic geometric proof that intersections of three tangents of a hyperbola are at right angle with respect to the foci

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Here is the construction I am looking at.

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ with respective vertices $V_1$ and $V_2$. Let $P$ be a point be closer to $F_2$ than $F_1$. Tangents are drawn from from $V_1,$ $V_2,$ and $P.$ As $V_1$ and $V_2$ are parallel the only intersections between the tangents come from the tangents $P/V_1$ and $P/V_2.$ Let these intersections be $Q$ and $R.$ Now, $\angle RF_1Q=90^{\circ}.$

Here is a picture:

[image]

This is the fact I want to prove geometrically. Most likely a straightforward analytical solution exists but I am more interested in how to approach this synthetically.

I've tried angle chasing based on the fact that the tangent $P$ bisects the angle $\angle F_1PF_2.$ But both my attempts at finding $\angle RF_1Q$ directly and trying to prove $F_1RF_2Q$ concyclic have failed.

Similarly, I've had trouble trying to find more about geometric properties of hyperbolas online as most websites discuss hyperbola using coordinates which I am trying to avoid here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the main proof, we need a nice lemma:

> The two tangents that can be drawn to a hyperbola from an external
> point subtend equal or supplementary angles at the focus, according as
> the points of contact are on the same or opposite branches of the
> curve.

I'll prove this lemma for the same branch case, the other case is similar. Let then $OQ$, $OQ'$ be two tangents from point $O$ to a hyperbola of focus $S$.
Let $Z$ be the intersection point of line $OQ$ with the directrix: we have then $SZ\perp SQ$ ([see here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953161/the-portion-of-the-tangent-to-any-conic-intercepted-between-the-point-of-contact/3953791#3953791)). Drop from $O$ the perpendiculars $OU$ to $SQ$ and $OI$ to the directrix (see figure below) and let $M$ be the projection of $Q$ on the directrix.

From similar triangles we have then:

$$ 
SU:SQ=ZO:ZQ=OI:QM,
$$
that is:
$$
SU={SQ\over QM}OI=e\,OI,
$$
where $e$ is the eccentricity of the hyperbola.
Considering tangent $OQ'$ we can analogously prove $SU'=e\,OI$,
where $U'$ is the projection of $O$ on $SQ'$.
Hence $SU=SU'$ and triangles $OSU$, $OSU'$ are congruent. It follows that
$\angle OSQ=\angle OSQ'$, as it was to be proved.

[image]

Let's prove now the requested property $\angle QF_1R=90°$.

From the above lemma we get:
$$
\angle V_1F_1R=\angle RF_1P,
\quad\text{and}\quad
\angle QF_1V_1+\angle QF_1P=180°
$$
and we have then:
$$
\begin{align}
2\angle QF_1V_1+\angle V_1F_1P &=180°\\
2\angle QF_1V_1+2\angle V_1F_1R &=180°\\
\angle QF_1V_1+\angle V_1F_1R &=90°\\
\angle QF_1R &=90°\\
\end{align}
$$
QED.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was much cleaner than I expected it to be.